# Remove characters wrapped around a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a comment form using a JavaScript @mention library which lets me save some comment text to my server like this `'This is a message for @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:53453) and @[JasonDavis](user:1)'`

When I go to show the comment HTML on the page I only need the name and not the user ID... `'This is a message for @Kenneth Auchenberg and @JasonDavis'`

I need to convert this string...

```
var commentStr = 'This is a message for @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:53453) and @[JasonDavis](user:1)';
```

into this string...

```
var cleanCommentStr = 'This is a message for @Kenneth Auchenberg and @JasonDavis';
```

How can I remove the bad characters wrapped around the names using JavaScript?

---

Update

I might just approach this differently and add a new column to my comments DB table to hold a list of @mentioned users and then simply remove this stuff from the comments before saving the comment text. I really only need the user ID when comment is created so I can generate a notification for that user. After that I can just show the users name in the comment text.

Comment: [This looks like a generalised solution](https://github.com/wooorm/strip-markdown).

Comment: @KenY-N I'm glad you pointed out the Markdown connection as I hadn't even noticed!  As my comments support markdown, I can simply leave as is and the username will show as a link even better thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with RegEx.

[**RegEx101 Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bN4mV5/1)

```
/@\[([\w\s]+)\][^)]+\)/
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `@\[([\w\s]+)\]`: Matches `@[` followed by any alphanumeric character, underscore, and spaces one or more number of times and then followed by `]`. The parenthesis `()` are used to put the username in the first captured group - `$1`.
2. `[^)]+\)`: Matches anything until `)`. Thus matching the string inside parenthesis after the `@[blah blah]`.
3. `g`: Global flag.

[image: Regex Visualization]

The replacement `@$1` will replace `@[blah blah](anything)` by `@blah blah`. Here `$1` is the first captured group i.e. The string inside the square brackets.

**Demo:**

```js
var commentStr = 'This is a message for @[Kenneth Auchenberg](user:53453) and @[JasonDavis](user:1)';

commentStr = commentStr.replace(/@\[([\w\s]+)\][^)]+\)/g, '@$1');

document.body.innerHTML = commentStr;
```

Comment: very nice! Im still trying to decide if I want to save the comment to DB with or without the id attached.  This opens possibilty to save it as is thank you.  Do you have any thoughts on which way to go?

Comment: @JasonDavis I think the processed string should be saved in DB, unless the library you're using provides any facility to use those userId and username in brackets.

Comment: The user in the comment made me see above that it is basically just a Markdown link...as my comments support markdown it makes the username show up as a link name and I didn't even realize so I might just leave it as is.  Thanks for your code though it is a great example and useful down the road for sure